# ngBootBox Callback Function Not Working (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootbox

I use [ngBootbox](https://github.com/eriktufvesson/ngBootbox) from eriktufvesson in my AngularJS app and as stated in  [BootBox.js Documentation](http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html) how to use callback function in alert:

```
bootbox.alert({
    message: "This is an alert with a callback!",
    callback: function () {
        console.log('This was logged in the callback!');
    }
})
```

This is my code:

```
$ngBootbox.alert({
    size: "small",
    title: "Error",
    message: message,
    backdrop: true,
    closeButton: false,
    callback: function () {
        //do something when modal closed right?
        console.log('hello');
        //it's not working right now!
    }
});
```

So, how to make the ngBootBox alert callback function working in AngularJS app?

Please give me enlightenment.

*note:
I also use ngBootBox confirm and it's working wonderfully, I just don't know how to deal with the ngBootbox Alert Callback Function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for ngBootBox](https://github.com/eriktufvesson/ngBootbox#ngbootboxalertmsg) discusses the `$ngBootbox.alert()`:

> Returns a promise that is resolved when the dialog is closed.

Therefore, instead of passing a traditional `callback`, you can chain onto the promise, like so:

```
$ngBootbox.alert({
    size: "small",
    title: "Error",
    message: message,
    backdrop: true,
    closeButton: false,
})
.then(function () {
    //do something when modal closed right?
    console.log('hello');
});
```

Comment: I didn't see that coming, it's in the front page of the documentation itself, i feel so stupid right now. Thanks a lot!